# Enable citation in doom emacs org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I am unable to make citations work in my doom emacs installation, from the manual it is not clear which changes I need to add to the config.

What I want:

```
#+bibliography: notebook.bib
This is text with citation [cite:@Knuth:1984]

* References


#+print_bibliography:
```

To generate a bibliography

The citation never gets identified when I export to html. The only change I have on doom emacs is the addition of:

```
       (org +pretty +present +beamer +dragndrop +lsp +org-cite)               ; organize your plain life in plain text
```

and

```
(package! org-ref)
```

- How to enable citations on org-mode doom emacs?